# What software do I need to exchange Bitcoins?

Tags: command-line, bitcoin

I need software that could run on Ubuntu desktops and server; a command-line one.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit both on the desktop and on the server.

What software can I use?

I have tried installing both [`bitcoin-qt`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592383/how-can-i-run-bitcoin-qt-on-ubuntu-14-04-amd64-the-one-from-official-ppa-keeps) and [`bitcoind`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592383/how-can-i-run-bitcoin-qt-on-ubuntu-14-04-amd64-the-one-from-official-ppa-keeps). I have tried compiling from source, [per this tutorial](http://bitzuma.com/posts/compile-bitcoin-core-from-source-on-ubuntu/). They all crash.

I figured there the official package called Bitcoin Core (of wich `bitcoin-qt` and `bitcoind` are partts) is not the only software available: [there are lots of wallets](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bitcoin-wallets/) that allow one to managa Bitcoin wallets. What is the command-line solution that works? There is one, right? Bitcoin is the #1 cryptocurrency, and Ubuntu LTS is a popular system, after all, so there should be a command-line solution that works, right?

If I need to check out a specific another version of Bitcoin Core (e.g. an earlier one) or apply some pathes or build flags, I'm ok with that. Anything taht I can roll into a script to run in a single step is fine with me, though I prefer the most 'official' solution possible. I'm actually pretty surprised that the binaries in the official ppa's are broken.

Comment: There are too many potential answers here.  (However, the only one with a true scriptable API is Bitcoin core)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used bitcoind on a pure headless server (no desktop / X packages installed) to automatically send and receive BTC, controlled by a PHP script. I assume that most bitcoin online services are hosted on Linux servers, so yes – there is a command-line solution that works.

Back then, bitcoind was definitely the way to go. You say "they all crash", but that is not very specific. Make sure you download the 0.10.0 source code tagged on GitHub and follow the [build instructions (Link)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0/doc/build-unix.md).

If it still crashes, it's either a bug in their bitcoind code (pretty unlikely?) or something went wrong during compilation. In that case, you should add more details about the crash in order to get help.